# Can i have multiple Matrix report within one report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Could someone please suggest if i can have multiple matrix reports within one SSRS report?

I tried to implement but it doesn't give me proper results for the 2nd matrix.

Comment: You can have as many tablix, or matrix, in one report that you need. What do you mean when you say the results in the 2nd matrix are not proper?

Comment: Yes you can, pls give more details why your second matrix did work. Perhaps what you did why it didn't work because it should work.

Comment: Hi, i am now able to make multiple matrices in a single report, i had made a mistake while configuring the column and row groups.